# transaction in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I want to write stored proc with transaction. Suppose, proc1 is calling another proc(proc2) in transaction block. proc2 also contains rollback/commit. If rollback happens in proc1, does rollback happen in proc2 also ??
I have tried following example but it didn't work.
Here is the following code

test1.sql

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug`.`test1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test1`()

begin

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET @errorOccurred :=2;

set @errorOccurred :=1;

START TRANSACTION;

insert into Table1 values("table1_1");

insert into debug values("insertStatement_1");

insert into Table1 values(1,2);

call test2();

if (@errorOccurred=2) then
ROLLBACK;
else
COMMIT;
end if;

end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

=========================================

test2.sql

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug`.`test2`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test2`()
begin
START TRANSACTION;

create table Table2 (msg varchar(255)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into Table2 values("table2_value");

COMMIT;

end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Could you please help me to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something interesting: Once you run [**START TRANSACTION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html), any open transaction will implicitly commit. I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange: [March 15, 2013 : MySQL backup InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36799/877).

**SUGGESTION** : I would remove `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` from test2.sql.

Give it a Try !!!

### UPDATE 2013-10-28 09:16 EDT

If you can calling a transaction within a transaction, you cannot do `START TRANSACTION` a second time. If you want to rollback from `test2` and keep `test1` in a transaction from the point of calling `test2`, you should look into using [**SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT in the MySQL Docuementation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html).

Basically, you would create the **SAVEPOINT** in `test1` just before calling `test2`. You would rollback to the **SAVEPOINT** if `test2` fails in anyway.

Comment: actually i jst mentioned here sample code but in our project transaction blk is necessary in another stored proc.